# What is this small box on the ceiling?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, ceiling, access-panel

There is this small removable box on the left hand corner of the ceiling in the duplex down that I'm looking at. Can someone help me understand what it is?

[image]

Comment: Clearly an access-panel of some kind. Is there some plumbing in the room above?

Comment: if you have a ladder long enough to reach it you can open it and have a look. Cut the paint along the outline of the door if needed with a utility knife, and use a large flat screwdriver to turn its lock. Keep your head to the side as you don't know what dust or debris might fall out. Take a picture, and we can help.

Comment: @P2000 the title bar on the image suggests that Ryan may not have physical access to this location.

Comment: @Jasen Title bar on the image isn't a guarantee, because it could be from a picture taken from a Listing and that he now Bought/Rented it. But "**that I'm looking at**" is pretty much a guarantee. Landlord may allow "look around in person" but unlikely to allow "climb up on a ladder and cut the paint etc."

Comment: Amended: "... provided you have been granted permission, implicitly or explicitly, to do so." Just in case OP thought it would be a good idea to engage in a covert operation, break in and climb such a ladder with knife in hand, in a stranger's home. Just in case.

Answer (score 6):

It is an access hatch.  To determine why it's there requires that you either open it and look, or know what is above it.   For example if there is a bath tub upstairs this could be for access to service it.  There could be an electrical junction box in it.   There could be nothing there.  Perhaps there was a light fixture or another air vent that was removed and the ceiling was repaired with this hatch because it's less work than plastering and then painting the entire ceiling.